# Adding A dropdown to a Scala Template with PlayFrameWork

Tags: scala, playframework

Can Anybody Help me Figure Out why my select component is not binding the item selected when I try to save. My Scala Template Code is below:

```
    @(subheadform: play.data.Form[SubHead])(mode: String)(budgetAccountOptions: java.util.HashMap[String, String])}
@main("Service info") {
<div class="page-header">
<h2>SubHead Information</h2>
</div>
<fieldset>
<legend> Budget(@mode)</legend>
@b3.form(action = routes.SubHeadController.save(mode)) {
  <input type ="hidden" name="mode" value="@mode"/>

  @b3.select( subheadform("code"), options= options(budgetAccountOptions), '_label -> "Select Budget Control",'_default -> "Select an option" )

  @if(mode == "Adding") {

  } else {
    @b3.text(subheadform("id"), '_label -> "Id", 'readOnly -> "readOnly")
  }
  @b3.text(subheadform("code"), '_label -> "Code", 'placeholder -> "Code")
  @b3.text(subheadform("description"), '_label -> "Description", 'maxlength -> 50, 'placeholder -> "Description")

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick= "window.location= '@routes.SubHeadController.listofSubHeads()';" value="cancel">
        Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}
</fieldset>
}
```

Below is my routes:

```
#------------------------------------ BUDGET-SUBHEAD ROUTES----------------

GET     /budgetsubhead                         controllers.SubHeadController.listofSubHeads()
GET     /budgetsubhead/new               controllers.SubHeadController.addSubHead()
GET     /budgetsubhead/edit/:code        controllers.SubHeadController.editSubHead(code: String)
POST    /budgetsubhead/save/:mode        controllers.SubHeadController.save(mode: String)
DELETE  /budgetsubhead/del/:code          controllers.SubHeadController.delete(code: String)
```

And Below is my Subhead Controller:

```
public class SubHeadController extends Controller {

private static Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of(SubHeadController.class);


private HashMap getMap() {
    List<BudgetAccount> budgetAccounts = BudgetAccount.findAll();

    HashMap budgetAccountOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for ( BudgetAccount budgetAccount : budgetAccounts ) {

        budgetAccountOptions.put(budgetAccount.id.toString(), budgetAccount.description);
    }
    return budgetAccountOptions;
}


public Result listofSubHeads() {

    List<SubHead> allSubheads = SubHead.findAll();
    return ok(listofsubheads.render(allSubheads));
    //return ok(Json.toJson(allServices));
}

public Result addSubHead() {
    Form<SubHead> newSubHeadForm = Form.form(SubHead.class);
    HashMap budgetAccountOptions = getMap();
    return ok(subheadpage.render(newSubHeadForm, ModeConst.ADD,budgetAccountOptions));
}




public Result save(String mode) {



    Form<SubHead> ourForm = Form.form(SubHead.class).bindFromRequest();
    HashMap budgetAccountOptions = getMap();
    //Logger.debug("Errors:" + ourForm.errors().toString());
    if (ourForm.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("Error");
        return badRequest(subheadpage.render(ourForm, mode,budgetAccountOptions));
    }

    SubHead subHead = ourForm.get();


    if (subHead != null) {
        if (ModeConst.ADD.equals(mode)) {
            if (SubHead.exists(subHead.code)) {
                flash("errorsFound", "SubHead year already exists");
                return badRequest(subheadpage.render(ourForm, mode,budgetAccountOptions));
            }
            subHead.save();
            return redirect(routes.SubHeadController.addSubHead());
        } else if (mode.startsWith(ModeConst.EDIT)) {
            subHead.update();
           return redirect(routes.SubHeadController.editSubHead(subHead.code));
        }
    }
    // flash("errorsFound","Please fix the errors on the page");
    return badRequest(subheadpage.render(ourForm, mode,budgetAccountOptions));
}

}
```

And this is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_head")
public class SubHead extends Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
public Long id;

public String code;

public String description;


@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public BudgetAccount budgetAccount;


private static Model.Finder<String, SubHead> find = new Model.Finder<String, SubHead>(SubHead.class);

public static List<SubHead> findAll() {
    return find.orderBy("code").findList();
}

public static SubHead retrieve(String code) {
    return find.where()
            .eq("code", code)
            .findUnique();
}

public static boolean exists(String code) {
    return (find.where().eq("code", code).findRowCount() == 1) ? true : false;

}
}
```

When I try to save, I get a NullPointer Exception.
Can Anyone figure out What I'm not doing right?
Thanks

Comment: Create a mcve for this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome. One of the issues appears to be that you have two fields with an id of "code", namely:

```
@b3.select( subheadform("code"), options= options(budgetAccountOptions), ...
...
@b3.text(subheadform("code"), '_label -> "Code", 'placeholder -> "Code")
```

So it seems to me there will be unpredictable results, perhaps depending on browsers.

Comment: Actually I figured it out Already. That was the problem.Thanks Alot. I'm new to Scala and Play in general. I'm wondering if you could more readily available in future, if i come up with a tough challenge. You could send a message to me on skype firstbeanman, or any other way you think i can contact you.. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. This is probably the best place to look for help. Write your questions as precisely as possible. Can't skype with at the moment I'm afraid! Too much on the go here :) Good luck and enjoy the journey!

Comment: Can you take a look at this challenge. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843484/how-to-save-through-a-list-into-the-database-using-play-framework-ebean