# How to save through a list into the Database, using play Framework ebean?

Tags: java, database, playframework, ebean

I'm trying to save through a list of subheads but with the same Department Id but different subheadDepartmentID. How do i Go about it?

```
subHeadDepartment.department= department;
    for(String thissubhead: ConstructedList){
         SubHead subHead = SubHead.retrievebyName(thissubhead);
         subHeadDepartment.subhead=subHead;
         subHeadDepartment.save();
        }
```

The code I have here is updating just the first subheadDepartment Id in the loop.While what i want is to create a subheaddepartmentId for each subhead entered but all will have same departmentId in the DB.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of SubHeadDepartment for each element you want to create:

```
for(String thissubhead: ConstructedList){
     SubHead subHead = SubHead.retrievebyName(thissubhead);
     SubHeadDepartment subHeadDepartment = new SubHeadDepartment();
     subHeadDepartment.department = department;
     subHeadDepartment.subhead = subHead;
     subHeadDepartment.save();
    }
```